# How to handle a PanResponder onPanResponderRelease event in a function component

Tags: react-native

I have a component that uses the PanResponder to create a joystick like control.  The problem I'm having is that if I tie into the onPanResponderRelease event the state is stale.  I believe this is caused by using useRef for the PanResponder.

```
const panResponder = useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([null, {dx: pan.x, dy: pan.y}]),
      onPanResponderRelease: () => {
        Animated.spring(
                    pan,
                    {
                        toValue: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                        },
                        useNativeDriver: false,
                    },
                ).start();
       props.onReleased(); //call the onReleased event so the parent can respond.
      },
    }),
  ).current;
```

Parent component

```
const onReleased = () => {
    //implement logic based on current state values
    if(someState .... //somestate is always the initial value

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer for this but I'd like some community feedback. If I move the release event outside the useRef everything works as expected.

```
const panResponder = useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([null, {dx: pan.x, dy: pan.y}]),
    }),
  ).current;

  panResponder.panHandlers.onResponderRelease = () => {
        Animated.spring(
                    pan,
                    {
                        toValue: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                        },
                        useNativeDriver: false,
                    },
                ).start();
        props.onRelease();
  }
```

Parent component

```
const onReleased = () => {
    //implement logic based on current state values
    if(someState .... //somestate now has the current value

  }
```

Here is a working example also: https://snack.expo.dev/lr5Wz8XwV

I'm not super familiar with the PanResponder so I'm wondering if this will be a performance issue.